# Connect function in raw socket?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp, raw-sockets

I am trying to initiate a TCP Three-Way-Handshake in C. However, it occurred to me that `connect` may already be establishing such a connection or in some way interfering. Does `connect` automatically establish a TCP connection whenever the socket it's called on has the `IPPROTO_TCP` option set?

Comment: What else would it do? Strange question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `IPPROTO_TCP` creates TCP socket. To use raw socket, you need to pass SOCK_RAW as second argument to the `socket` function.

Comment: Well see, I have the second parameter as `SOCK_RAW` but it's coupled with `IPPROTO_TCP` as the third parameter. In retrospect I should have clarified, I apologize. I am wondering how the two together would effect the behavior of `connect`.

Comment: In this case, I would not expect connect to actually succeed. Never tried it myself, but I would expect it to fail.

Comment: Why would you expect it not to succeed?

Comment: @ArthurJames, because `connect` would require one of the higher level socket types, like 'SOCK_STREAM' or 'SOCK_DGRAM' type, not `SOCK_RAW`. Does it work in your experiment?

Answer (score 1):

Per MSDN documentation:

[TCP/IP Raw Sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548.aspx)

> Once an application creates a socket of type `SOCK_RAW`, this socket may be used to send and receive data. **All packets sent or received on a socket of type `SOCK_RAW` are treated as datagrams on an unconnected socket**.
>
> The following rules apply to the operations over `SOCK_RAW` sockets:
>
> ...
>
> Received datagrams are copied into all `SOCK_RAW` sockets that satisfy the following conditions:
>
> ...
>
> - If a foreign address is defined for the socket, it should correspond to the source address as specified in the IP header of the received datagram. **An application may specify the foreign IP address by calling the `connect` or `WSAConnect` function**. If no foreign IP address is specified for the socket, the datagrams are copied into the socket regardless of the source IP address in the IP header of the received datagram.

This implies that RAW sockets are essentially connection-less sockets, and thus `connect()` *does not* perform a 3-way TCP handshake on a RAW socket. It simply associates a remote address with the socket, similar to how `connect()` works with a UDP (`SOCK_DGRAM`) socket.

More importantly:

> Limitations on Raw Sockets
>
> ...
>
> - **TCP data cannot be sent over raw sockets.**
>     ...
> - **A call to the `bind` function with a raw socket for the `IPPROTO_TCP` protocol is not allowed.**

So you can't use `IPPROTO_TCP` with a RAW socket to begin with, so the matter of `connect()` behavior on a RAW TCP socket is moot. [`IPPROTO_TCP` can only be used with a real TCP (`SOCK_STREAM`) socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506.aspx):

> IPPROTO_TCP
>   6
>
> The Transmission Control Protocol (TCP). This is a possible value when the `af` parameter is `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` **and the `type` parameter is `SOCK_STREAM`**.