# No Data Transmission Over TCP Socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, netcat

I have two virtual machines running. Both are Ubuntu 18.04. Host OS is Windows 10. The virtual machines have IP  `10.0.2.10 (A)` and `10.0.2.11 (B)`. Now I wrote the following `C` code to send a UDP message from `B` to `A`.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    struct sockaddr_in dest_info;
    char *data = "UDP message\n";

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    memset((char *) &dest_info, 0, sizeof(dest_info));
    dest_info.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest_info.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.2.10");
    dest_info.sin_port = htons(9090);

    sendto(sock, data, strlen(data), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &dest_info, sizeof(dest_info));
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

I run the following command on the terminal of `A`:

```
nc -luv 9090
```

Now I run the program from `B` Which gives the following output on `A`:

```
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 9090)
Connection from 10.0.2.11 33849 received!
UDP message
```

Just as expected. Now I change the parameters a bit:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    struct sockaddr_in dest_info;
    char *data = "TCP message\n"; // <------ Changed the message

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP); // <--- Changed parameter here

    memset((char *) &dest_info, 0, sizeof(dest_info));
    dest_info.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest_info.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.2.10");
    dest_info.sin_port = htons(9090);

    sendto(sock, data, strlen(data), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &dest_info, sizeof(dest_info));
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

On terminal of `A`:

```
 nc -lv 9090
```

Now running the program from `B` doesn't give any output on `A`:

```
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 9090)
```

It just sits there without showing any output. What is going wrong with TCP transmission?

Comment: You have to *connect* a TCP socket. You also have to check the result of all system calls. The `sendto()` failed here, but your code didn't detect it.

Comment: I ran my code `sudo ./a.out`. And printed `sock` and return value of `sendto`. It printed `3` and `12` respectively. If it failed, wouldn't it return something less than `0`?

Comment: Didn't I connect a TCP socket? If not, how would I do that? @user207421

Comment: You call `connect(sock, ...)`.

Comment: Why are you using `SOCK_RAW` instead of `SOCK_STREAM`?

Comment: @Barmar Actually I should've included the details. I'm trying to do a TCP Reset Attack over video streaming application. I need to set the packet manually. That's why I'm using `SOCK_RAW`.

Comment: I'm not an expert in raw sockets, but I think you need to construct the TCP header by hand, it won't be filled in automatically, even though you specified `IPPROTO_TCP`.

Comment: I did that in my code for the Reset Attack. You can have a look here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Nbb6K9YqGr/

Comment: The end result is the same. No packet is transmitted.

Comment: "If it failed, wouldn't it return something less than 0..." Actually if it doesn't return 0, then there is an issue with sending of the packet and you need to see what return values 3 and 12 signify.

Comment: I would suggest printing `errno` and its string message using `strerror(errno)`.

Comment: `fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));`  gives `socket() failed: Success`. What does it mean?

Comment: It returns positive because it is a file descriptor. Why would that be an issue? @kiner_shah

Comment: It doesn't mean file descriptor. See [this](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto). It returns the number of bytes sent or -1 in case of error. When did you print the `strerror`, after sendto? If that's the case then I think there is some different issue. You may use `tcpdump` or Wireshark to trace the packets sent via the network. You may be able to find something out.

Comment: My program doesn't return `-1`. It returns `12`, the number of bytes send. `sock` is a file descriptor here whose value is `3`. I don't get what you're saying.

Comment: I think I am a bit confused. Can you mention the code of the receiving end?

Comment: replace the `sendto(...)` with this: `if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &dest_info, sizeof(dest_info)) < 0) { fprintf(stderr, ...); } else { if (send(sock, data, strlen(data), 0) < 0) { fprintf(stderr, ...); } }`
    `

Comment: @RemyLebeau, isn't `connect` required when SOCK_STREAM is used? For SOCK_RAW is `connect` really required?

Comment: @kiner_shah [Connect function in raw socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369086/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau, ohh yeah, that does clear it!

Comment: @kiner_shah Actually `sendto()` returns the number of bytes transmitted, which can be >= 0, or -1 if an error occurred. Return values 3 and 12 are byte counts. They don't 'signify' anything else.

Comment: @user207421, yeah I had got that!